# Inserting images into a title page

Tags: graphics, titles, includegraphics

I've started with Latex just today and I seem incapable of adequately comprehending this entire image insertion issue. The explanations on the internet seem relatively tranquil and generally facile, I follow them step by step and the code I type doesn't function. Please help, I am in profound need of aid. I just turned 14, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{Party BOD Constitution}
\author{Skander Lejmi}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\includegraphics{ {IMg/coatofarms} }
\paragraph{We The People}
of the Party BOD have produced this paper with the intention of ensuring the tranquillity of upcoming parties, facilitating the proliferation of perfection within these parties, establishing fundamental rules that will hitherto be submitted to and further improve the unity of \textbf{\textit{Party BOD}} are profoundly appreciative of our \textit{Party BOD constitution.}

\end{titlepage}
```

[image: Image of file directory]

If anyone can aid me it will be seriously appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) LaTeX is not, as many other languages, "free form". That is, you cannot, in most cases, add spaces and braces at will. When you do `\includegraphics{ {IMg/coatofarms} }`, LaTeX expects an image named `{IMg/coatofarms}`, with spaces and braces included. Remove the extra braces and spaces and, if nothing else is wrong, it should work: `\includegraphics{IMg/coatofarms}`.

Comment: Great that you are using LaTex Skander.  We don't know what operating system you are on -- in addition to the above try making the image and your call to it of matched case (i.e rename the file to coatofarms.png all in lower case). Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you for your swift provision of aid, it still seems not to identify the location of the file.

Comment: Make sure that the file extension is correct. It might help lowercasing it (`.PNG` -> `.png`)

Comment: Ive attempted resolving the issue with all the information provided by all of you yet it still doesn't seem to function. I tried the exact same code on texstudio and the functionality was absent as well.

Comment: Also, you don't have `\end{document}`

Comment: I tried this locally to make it compile. This is what I did: first lowercase the file name and file extension. Next, change the `\includegraphics{ {IMg/coatofarms} }`-line to `\includegraphics{IMg/coatofarms}`, and then add the `\end{document}` at the bottom of your file.

Comment: Did both things indicated above and it still doesn't work, I suspect I've gotten the directory indication wrong could you show me how you did it. Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: I only did what I indicated above. Make sure that the file you’re trying to build is in the appropriate relative directory. Couple of last things to try are making the directory lowercase, and try with a different image (so you know it’s not the image it’s something wrong with).

Comment: @Andreas do you want to add some kind of answer? Maybe also explaining that using \maketitle in a title page environment is wrong?

Comment: No, it's fine :) You can just write an answer if you'd like :)